# How to create different forms for different views?

Tags: list, form

If I have one (1) list, is there a way to have two (2) New Forms, two (2) Edit Forms, and two (2) View Forms for two (2) different views?

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoint Designer to create as many Forms as you want.

There can only be one **default** Form for each of the three types.

So you will have to format the link to *non-default* Forms yourself in Views.

You need an item ID to pass to your *non-default* Form, and you can **not** use ID in a Formula.

Plenty of StackOverflow posts written how to work around the limitations.

This Calculated Column Formula set to datatype=Number gets you started in creating links to your own forms:

```
="<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
&"var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"
&"var id=TR.getAttribute( 'iid' ).split(',')[1];"
&"this.parentNode.innerHTML='<a href=MYFORM.aspx?ID='+id+'>to MyForm</a>';"
&"}"">"
```

Explanation at: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Another (and more lines of code) approach is to create all links with [CSR](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)

*Mark your StackOverflow questions as Answered, it will get all of us more credits, and make StackOverflow more valuable*